# Top de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I just realized that I never really understood why $H_{dR}^n(M, \mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$ if $M$ is compact  and $H_{dR}^n(M, \mathbb{R}) = \{0\}$ if $M$ is not compact (provided that's true?).

I'm assuming here (in both cases) that $M$ is a connected orientable smooth $n$-manifold (without boundary).

Is there an elementary way to explain this?

By "elementary", I mean for instance that I'm okay with accepting "technical lemmas" such as : *A compactly supported $n$-form $\alpha \in \Omega(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is exact iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \alpha = 0$* but I don't want to hear of singular homology, say.

Comment: You need to assume also that $M$ is orientable and connected for the first case. These are special cases of Poincare duality.

Comment: Well, every differential $n$-form is closed, and if $M$ is compact, we can integrate any differential $n$-form over all of $M$. Since $M$ is orientable, it has a volume form, say $\omega$. Then for any other differential $n$-form $\alpha$, we can consider $\beta = \alpha - (\frac{1}{V} \int_M \alpha) \omega$, where $V = \int_M \omega$. Clearly, $\int_M \beta = 0$. So then it suffices to show that differential $n$-forms with vanishing integral are exact.

Comment: @John:
1. I said $M$ is orientable and connected (read next sentence)
2. I believe it's the other way around: this is a prerequisite to show Poincaré duality

Comment: @ZhenLin: Sure, for the compact case (I'm aware of that)